# como puedo extraer los valores de un diccionario y añadirlos a una lista?

Tags: python, xml, csv

tengo un fichero xml que filtro para que solo me aparezcan los type_id=1 con el siguiente código:

```
for elem in root:
    for nodo in root.iterfind(".//*[@type_id='1']"):
        print(nodo.attrib)
```

y obtengo el siguiente resultado ( es solo un trozo para el ejemplo):

```
{'id': '1372839298', 'event_id': '3', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '1', 'player_id': '37572', 'team_id': '43', 'outcome': '1', 'x': '50.1', 'y': '50.0', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:00:40.179', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:00:41'}
{'id': '978322590', 'event_id': '4', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '2', 'player_id': '20664', 'team_id': '43', 'outcome': '1', 'x': '48.2', 'y': '49.1', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:00:41.585', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:00:44'}
{'id': '1962550717', 'event_id': '7', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '19', 'player_id': '42593', 'team_id': '43', 'outcome': '0', 'x': '27.8', 'y': '100.0', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:00:58.445', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:01:01'}
{'id': '1886599927', 'event_id': '5', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '23', 'player_id': '27696', 'team_id': '30', 'outcome': '1', 'x': '50.9', 'y': '20.0', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:01:02.466', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:01:17'}
```

previamente cree unas listas vacías de la siguiente forma:

```
equipo = []
tiempo = []
minuto = []
segundo = []
origenX = []
origenY = []
destinoX = []
destinoY = []
resultado = []
```

y ahora no consigo extraer los valores de min, sec, player, team, x, y para añadirlos a la listas creadas. No se donde puede estar el error. Intente con algo del estilo:

```
newlist = []
keys = [ 'period_id', 'min', 'sec', 'player_id', 'team_id' ]
for d in range(len(keys)):
    newlist.append([])
for dicts in stuff:
    for k in range(len(keys)):
        newlist[k].append(dicts[keys[k]])
print(newlist)
```

siendo stuff todo el resultado que me da en los de {'id': '1372839298', 'event_id': '3',.... pero me devuelve el error

```
string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Agrega el código con el qué estas agregando a los valores a las listas. Verifica que {'id': '1372839298', 'event_id': '3', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '1', 'player_id': '37572', 'team_id': '43', 'outcome': '1', 'x': '50.1', 'y': '50.0', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:00:40.179', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:00:41'} Es un diccionario y no un string.

Comment: listo pero no me funciona dicho código :(

Answer (score 0):

He supuesto que puedes agrupar los diccionarios en una lista tal y como te lo muestro en este código, después es solo recorrer la lista de diccionarios y a su vez cada diccionario y cuando coincidan los ids agregarlos a la lista que desees.

Lo he hecho con las variables equipo y segundos como ejemplo pero sería igual con todas.

```
mydic = [{'id': '1372839298', 'event_id': '3', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '1', 'player_id': '37572', 'team_id': '43', 'outcome': '1', 'x': '50.1', 'y': '50.0', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:00:40.179', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:00:41'},
    {'id': '978322590', 'event_id': '4', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '2', 'player_id': '20664', 'team_id': '43', 'outcome': '1', 'x': '48.2', 'y': '49.1', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:00:41.585', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:00:44'},
    {'id': '1962550717', 'event_id': '7', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '19', 'player_id': '42593', 'team_id': '43', 'outcome': '0', 'x': '27.8', 'y': '100.0', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:00:58.445', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:01:01'},
    {'id': '1886599927', 'event_id': '5', 'type_id': '1', 'period_id': '1', 'min': '0', 'sec': '23', 'player_id': '27696', 'team_id': '30', 'outcome': '1', 'x': '50.9', 'y': '20.0', 'timestamp': '2011-08-21T16:01:02.466', 'last_modified': '2011-08-21T16:01:17'}
]


equipo = []
tiempo = []
minuto = []
segundo = []
origenX = []
origenY = []
destinoX = []
destinoY = []
resultado = []

for i, v in enumerate(mydic):
    for j in v:
        if j == 'team_id':
            equipo.append(mydic[i][j])
        elif j == 'sec':
            segundo.append(mydic[i][j])

print(equipo)
print(segundo)
```

Salida:

```
['43', '43', '43', '30']
['1', '2', '19', '23']
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

**Nota:**

Para crear la lista `mydic` del código de arriba, prueba lo siguiente:

```
mydic = []

for elem in root:
    for nodo in root.iterfind(".//*[@type_id='1']"):
        mydic.append(nodo.attrib)
```

Comment: Pero tengo un problema yo al mostrar el resultado que tú llamas "mydic" no tengo una "," al final de cada resultado y es que es una gran cantidad de filas como para ponerlo de manera manual.

No sé si hay alguna manera de insertarle una "," al final de cada resultado ( de cada frase ) y crear un diccionario de dicho resultado

Comment: pero si el código funciona

Comment: Si cada diccionario lo obtienes con print(nodo.attrib), en vez de ´print´ crea al inicio una lista vacía (Ej: mydic = []) y cambia `print(nodo.attrib)` por `mydic.append(nodo.attrib)` de esta forma creo que se creará justamente la lista que he puesto en el ejemplo.

Comment: He editado la respuesta, mira la nota del final.